# heightForRowAtindexPath not called after tableView.beginUpdates in ios 15

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

Before iOS 15 after I made

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

method heightForRowAtindexPath was called and my cell height changed without reloading data in the cell. Now in iOS 15 this not works! How can I force reload tableview cell height without reloading data in this cell?

Comment: Absolutely the same problem. Found it just a few minutes ago. Temporarily replaced beginUpdated() and endUpdates() with reloadData() until I find a solution

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about your code. Quick test, and it's working as expected for me.

Comment: Side note... Apple's docs state **"Use the `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` method instead of this one whenever possible."**

Comment: @DonMag , performBatchUpdates(_:completion:) also doesn't work

Comment: @Viktoria, It works, but all changes are without animations

Comment: @TimYumalin updated the question with a working solution for me

Comment: I don't have a device upgraded to iOS 15 yet, but this runs fine on iPhone Simulator: https://pastebin.com/PgWPN6QX

Answer (score 6):

I have already solved the problem. Apparently, Apple made a change in the way updates are processed and cell sizes are adjusted.

As the "hidden" cell is left at 0, when sending the `beginUpdate`, it only processes the cells that have a value greater than 0, so that is why it no longer adjusts them.

What you need to do is change the value of 0, returned for hidden cells, to 0.01, and you're done!

I hope this solution works the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

1. In **heightForRowAtindexPath** method return for resizable cell **UITableView.automaticDimension** instead of size
2. Inside my custom tableView cell I added height constraint to my container view (in my case this is webView)
3. In a place where I get cell size and need to update height (for me after webView content was loaded), I update height contraint:

.

```
cell.heightContraint.constant = size
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

So the cell is autoresizable now with **UITableView.automaticDimension** height and, of course, your view/container view should have top and bottom constraints equal to cell`s top and bottom constraints