# Why the show/ hide table view mechanism doesn't work in non iPhone SE simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am using the following mechanism, to perform `UITableView`'s row show and hide.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var hiddenIndexPaths : Set<IndexPath> = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func toggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            show(1)
            show(2)
        } else {
            hide(1)
            hide(2)
        }
    
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
    private func isHidden(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        hiddenIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)
    }
    
    private func hide(_ item: Int) {
        hiddenIndexPaths.insert(IndexPath(item: item, section: 0))
    }
    
    private func show(_ item: Int) {
        hiddenIndexPaths.remove(IndexPath(item: item, section: 0))
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if isHidden(indexPath) {
            return 0.0
        }
        
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it works great in iPhone SE simulator (Works well in iPhone SE real device too)

### iPhone SE simulator

[image]

---

However, in non iPhone SE simulator (Like iPhone 13), once the table row is hidden, it can no longer be shown. Please refer to the following video.

### iPhone 13 simulator

[image]

I am not sure what will its behavior in iPhone 13 real device, because I do not have access.

I was wondering, do you have any idea why such issue occurs?

If you are interested to test, here's the complete workable sample - https://github.com/yccheok/show-hide-table-row-bug

### Testing environment

- XCode Version 14.0 (14A309)
- macOS Monterey Version 12.6 (M1)
- Simulator iPhone 13, iOS 15

Comment: I checked on iPhone 13 Simulator and its working fine. Review this for more info https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj-_XGYZ-SE2d-LYWVcyIxvd7T0?e=v3t1jp

Comment: May I know what version of Xcode are u using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 14.0

Comment: I think possible reason is that, you are testing using iPhone 13 simulator iOS 16. What if, you test using iPhone 13 simulator iOS 15?

Comment: Yes I am facing that issue with iOS 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem replace:

```
return 0.0
```

with

```
return 0.01
```

in your `heightForRowAt` method.

For more detail please refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583818/heightforrowatindexpath-not-called-after-tableview-beginupdates-in-ios-15) post.